# Strategy for Implement increasing id in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, solr, auto-increment, solr4

We want to build an auto increment field in a our dataindex, basically something like the twitterId of a tweet.

We want to provide data to client based on sinceId and untilId, what can be the best strategy to get this done. Our data is stored in Solr and also HBase.

Regards,

Ayush.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no such feature in Solr. You can use an approach like this [1] which uses UUID. In addition, as you mentioned HBase, please have a look at

- this interesting paper [2]
- the HBase documentation [3]

depending on your context, monotonically incremented identifiers are not so good (and here the UUID approach comes again useful)

---

[1] http://solr.pl/en/2013/07/08/automatically-generate-document-identifiers-solr-4-x
[2] http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can UUID be incremental in any way. My problem I want to implement sort on this field and also they need to be unique.

Comment: You could split the two things: use a UUID as unique key and and another field (timestamp-based) as sort field.

Comment: tried that approach, the problem is two object being processed by different threads sometimes get the same timestamp. Some documents go missing in a pagination scenario.